# Será posible (en un futuro) agregar fragmentos de código ejecutable en el Spanish Language Beta

Tags: petición-de-funcionalidad

Acabo de ver esta pregunta en el Spanish Language Beta: [¿Existe una versión del “color carne” no racista?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/16735/existe-una-versi%C3%B3n-del-color-carne-no-racista). Quise contestar la pregunta agregando un fragmento de código con algunos nombres de colores utilizados en el diseño web, y me di cuenta que no es posible. Creo que poder agregar código habría sido una funcionalidad interesante y útil. Mi pregunta es: ¿Será posible (en un futuro) agregar fragmentos de código ejecutable?

Comment: ¿Te refieres a poder poner [code snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) que se puedan ejecutar directamente en la respuesta?

Comment: Sí, a esto me refiero.

Comment: Mmmm supongo que se podría pedir, pues es una funcionalidad que [se] activa en los sitios que lo necesitan. Sin embargo, creo que hay pocas situaciones en las que nuestro sito vaya a necesitarlo, por lo que veo difícil que nos lo concedieran. Por lo pronto, un enlace a un jsfiddle o alguna captura de pantalla podrían servir.